# React Native ./gradlew bundleRelease or assembleRelease command loads infinitely

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I need to get the AAB and APK file that the `bundleRelease` and `assembleRelease` generate in the android > app `build` folder. However for some reason I'm not able to get it because whenever I run one of those commands they would hang in the `app:multiDexListRelease` step.

I'm running React Native 0.63.2 version

Here's the log that I'm getting so far: Ran these commands multiple times and as you can see at the end of the log, they would take a crazy amount of time without timing out.

```
 android git:(master) ✗ ./gradlew bundleRelease

> Configure project :app
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed soon. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

> Configure project :react-native-firebase
react-native-firebase: using React Native prebuilt binary from /Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/node_modules/react-native/android

> Configure project :react-native-orientation
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed soon. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

> Task :react-native-community_geolocation:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: /Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/node_modules/@react-native-community/geolocation/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/geolocation/GeolocationModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-community_netinfo:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-community_async-storage:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: /Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStorageModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-community_art:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-community_datetimepicker:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-community_slider:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: /Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/node_modules/@react-native-community/slider/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/slider/ReactSliderManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/node_modules/@react-native-community/slider/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/slider/ReactSliderManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :react-native-community_toolbar-android:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-date-picker:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: /Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/node_modules/react-native-date-picker/android/src/main/java/com/henninghall/date_picker/DatePickerManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :react-native-fbsdk:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/Utility.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
warning: the transform cache was reset.
                 Welcome to React Native!
                Learn once, write anywhere



> Task :react-native-image-picker:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-maps:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :react-native-reanimated:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: /Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/reanimated/NodesManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/reanimated/NodesManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :react-native-screens:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :react-native-firebase:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
info Writing bundle output to:, /Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle
info Writing sourcemap output to:, /Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/generated/sourcemaps/react/release/index.android.bundle.map
info Done writing bundle output
info Done writing sourcemap output
info Copying 119 asset files
info Done copying assets

> Task :app:processReleaseGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/google-services.json

> Task :app:processReleaseManifest
/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31:50 Warning:
        activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:launchMode was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:24 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libhermes-inspector.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/arm64-v8a/libnative-filters.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARM64_V8A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/arm64-v8a/libjsijniprofiler.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARM64_V8A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/arm64-v8a/libimagepipeline.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARM64_V8A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/arm64-v8a/libhermes-executor-release.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARM64_V8A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/x86_64/libfbjni.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/x86_64/libreactnativeblob.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/x86_64/libimagepipeline.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.

> Task :app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
Compatible side by side NDK version was not found.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libnative-filters.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libfbjni.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libreactnativeblob.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libnative-imagetranscoder.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libjsijniprofiler.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libjsinspector.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libfolly_json.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libglog.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libimagepipeline.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libglog_init.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libfolly_futures.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libhermes-executor-debug.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libhermes-executor-release.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libfb.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libjscexecutor.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libreactnativejni.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libyoga.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/x86/libhermes-inspector.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/x86/libnative-filters.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/x86/libfbjni.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/x86/libreactnativeblob.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/x86/libnative-imagetranscoder.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/x86/libjsc.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/x86/libjsijniprofiler.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/x86/libjsinspector.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/x86/libfolly_json.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/x86/libglog.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.

Unable to strip library '/Users/aeum3893/Documents/work/miami_dev_shop/boatrax/mobile-app2.0/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/release/out/lib/x86/libyoga.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.

Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted
Exception in thread "Device List Monitor" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
<============-> 99% EXECUTING [27m 16s]
> :app:multiDexListRelease
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> IDLE
> :app:mergeReleaseJavaResource
> IDLE
> IDLE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it solved.

This was a combination of stuff that was happening and it may differ from project to project. There are different reasons of why this could be happening, but all of them has to do with the Daemons that get spin up when `gradle` does it's job.

But long story short, what worked for me was to:

> Open Activity Monitor (Task Manager on Windows), check for any Java
> processes and terminate them.

Then I would run again the command `./gradlew bundleRelease` or `./gradlew assembleRelease`.

I have also read that these Daemons after some time (couple hours I guess) would stop by themselves.